# How do I conform to a protocol with an actor?

Tags: swift, actor, swift-protocols

When I try to define an `actor` that conforms to a `protocol`, Xcode gives me the error `Actor-isolated instance method 'foo()' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement`. I can make the func `nonisolated` I don't think I want to. Do I need to? What would I be losing if I do so?

Here's the example code that causes the error:

```
protocol Fooable {
    func foo() -> Int
}

actor Bar: Fooable { // Error: Actor-isolated instance method...
    func foo() -> Int {
        return 42
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you tap on the “auto fix” button in front of the error message it will expand to show you two options:

[image]

In short, you can either:

- Add `nonisolated` to `foo()` to make this instance method not isolated to the actor:

  ```swift
  protocol Fooable {
      func foo() -> Int
  }

  actor Bar: Fooable {
      nonisolated func foo() -> Int {
          return 42
      }
  }
  ```
- Mark the protocol requirement `foo()` `async` to allow actor-isolated conformance:

  ```swift
  protocol Fooable {
      func foo() async -> Int
  }

  actor Bar: Fooable {
      func foo() -> Int {
          return 42
      }
  }
  ```

In short, the protocol needs to know whether the method can be called synchronously across actor-boundaries or not (i.e., whether it is nonisolated or not).

---

You asked whether you could use  `nonisolated`:

> What would I be losing if I do so?

If it is `nonisolated`, the method simply cannot directly access actor-isolated properties nor call actor-isolated methods. As the method currently stands, you can safely make it `nonisolated`.

In short, if a method does not require actor-isolation, you should generally feel free to mark it as `nonisolated`.